# possible mistaken empty statement

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I have come across an issue called a "Possible mistaken empty statement" now I have done a lot of research on this topic, and the solution I was given was to remove the semi colon after the if statement, however this only produces more warnings and more errors that I currently do not know the solution to, I would very much appreciate the help, the language I am using is C#.

```
if (checkBox5.Checked = true) ;
Double value5 = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox4.Checked);
value5 = +1;
Double result5 = value5;
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(result5);
```

Answer (score 9):

I *guess* that this is what you want:

```
if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
{
    double value5 = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox4.Checked) + 1;
    label2.Text = value5.ToString();
}
```

`=` is assigment, whereas `==` is checking for equality, on the other hand semicolon after `if` will terminate whole `if` statement.

Note that when you are checking for `true` then you can use this:

```
if (checkBox5.Checked) {  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use;

```
if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
```

not

```
if (checkBox5.Checked = true)
```

`=` is *assignment operator*, `==` is *equality operator*.

Check out;

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth(v=vs.110).aspx

And or course when you check your true value, you can use your if condition like;

```
if (checkBox5.Checked)
{
  // Do something if checkBox5 is checked.
}
```

And if you use semicolon after your if condition;

```
if (checkBox5.Checked = true) ;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (checkBox5.Checked = true) { }
```

So in your case I think you shouldn't use semicolon either. Because if you use it, your code will be look like;

```
if (checkBox5.Checked = true)
{

}

Double value5 = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox4.Checked);
value5 = +1;
Double result5 = value5;
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(result5);
```

which I assume you don't want to do this. And remember, even if there is no body to execute, doesn't mean that the loop terminates.

Comment: The OP asked for _"Possible mistaken empty statement"_ error, which was triggered by the semicolon in the `if` statement. Maybe that part should go first in the answer.

Moreover `value5 = +1;` seems suspicious, should be noted in the answer. Otherwise this would be my favourite answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the semi-colon at the end of your if as well as the single '=', should be:

```
if (checkBox5.Checked = true) ;
```

Should be:

```
if (checkBox5.Checked == true) // double '==' for equality comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @des and @Soner answers, why don't you just do this :

```
if (checkBox5.Checked)

    label2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox5.Checked).ToString();
```

I'm assuming you don't intend to increment `value5` by `1` as it should be `value5 += 1;`

Comment: This leaves out the addition of 1.

Comment: @juharr `value5 = +1;` will not add 1 to it :-) , it should be `value5 += 1;`

Comment: True, but the intend was almost assuredly to increment the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkBox5.Checked == true) ; // or you can use if (checkBox5.Checked)
//                     ^------------------- `=` assignment operator must be `==` equals
{  // missed 
    Double value5 = Convert.ToDouble(checkBox4.Checked);
    value5 = +1;
//          ^_______________ I assume you need `=+` addition assignment operator instead
//                                     assigning `+1` to `value5 `
    Double result5 = value5;
    label2.Text = Convert.ToString(result5);
} /// missed
```